# S3 - Upload - how to generate a pre-signed url that gives EVERYONE read access to the object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3

I'm trying to provide a pre-signed url that, once the image is uploaded, grants the group **Everyone** read access to the uplodaded image. 
So far, I'm generating the pre-signed url with the following steps:

```
    val req = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(params.s3Bucket,"$uuid.jpg",HttpMethod.PUT)
    req.expiration = expiration
    req.addRequestParameter("x-amz-acl","public-read")
    req.addRequestParameter("ContentType","image/jpeg")
    val url: URL = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(req)
```

But the image, once I check in S3, does not have the expected read access.

Comment: What does `does not have the expected read access` mean? Any errors? What error code do you get from S3?

Comment: this might help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html

Comment: What do you mean by "the group Everyone"? (That is a Windows term, which is not applicable to AWS.) Are you wanting to make the object accessible to anyone in the world, so they can access it at any time with no time limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP client that performs the upload needs to include the `x-amz-acl: public-read` header.

In your example, you're generating a request that includes that header. But, then you're generating a presigned [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html?is-external=true) from that request.

URLs don't contain HTTP headers, so whatever HTTP client you're using to perform the actual upload is not sending setting the header when it sends the request to the generated URL.

Answer (score 0):

This simple answer is working for me.

val url = getS3Connection()!!.generatePresignedUrl(
"bucketname", "key",
Date(Date().time + 1000 * 60 * 300)
)